# NSTimeZone isDaylightSavingTime giving wrong value

Tags: ios, objective-c, dst, nstimezone

Currently GMT-0700(US/pacific) is already in day-light-saving

But I am getting "NO" from NSTimeZone

```
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:secondsFromGMT]; //Getting timezone as GMT-0700 
BOOL isDaylightSavingTime = [timeZone isDaylightSavingTime]; //getting boolean value as NO
```

How to fix this issue?

REQUIREMENT :I want to know ,my receiver is using dayLightSavingTime or not.i will get only receiver offset value.I have to support different timezones()..What is the best approach to do this

Answer (score 2):

`timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT` is not specific enough.

The most accurate way is to create the time zone with the (full) region name:

```
NSTimeZone* timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Los_Angeles"];
```

Comment: Just a very basic question if i want to check "isDayLight".why should i use "PST"

Comment: Really, Apple should deprecate `timeZoneWithAbbreviation`. There are different time zones with the same abbreviation, e.g. "Philippine Standard Time". Also, the variant with daylight saving time is sometimes abbreviated "PDT".

Comment: The daylight saving time depends strongly on the region. Only the difference to UTC is too ambiguous.

Comment: we should support these timezones (Pacific, eastern,central,mountain) and should check it is daylightsaving or not. how ccan i do this

Comment: `America/Los_Angeles` is the most correct value to use.  `US/Pacific` would work also, but it is primarily there for backwards compatibility.  I recommend removing the part about the abbreviation. There are lots of problems with time zone abbreviations and they should generally be avoided.

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks for the hint. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a wrong value. You get timezone GMT-0700 but this is not a Pacific timezone. To create pacific timezone you need:

```
timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"PST"];
```

This is short description from apple documentation:

> **+ (instancetype)timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:(NSInteger)seconds;**
>
> Description Returns a time zone object offset from Greenwich Mean
>   Time by a given number of seconds. The name of the new time zone is
>   GMT +/– the offset, in hours and minutes. **Time zones created with this
>   method never have daylight savings**, and the offset is constant no
>   matter the date.

Comment: PST?  I have never heard of a time zone with that name.  I have heard of US/Pacific.

Comment: You also can use this string to create timezone.

Comment: PST is an abbreviation.  See the documentation.  https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nstimezone

Comment: Just a very basic question if i want to check "isDayLight".why should i use "PST"

Comment: You can use US/Pacific or some else timezone. But you can't use **timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT** to get isDayLight. Because when you create timezone with tis method is not a specific timezone like Pacific or Central European Time. This is timezone with name GMT +/– the offset.

Comment: The abbreviations are not standardized and actually depend on the language you use. PST can also mean "Philippine Standard Time". Really, don't use the abbreviations to create a time zone. Use them only to display them to users.

Comment: You wrong "Philippine Standard Time" = PHT, "Pakistan Standard Time" = PKT. TimeZone abbreviations is standardized

Comment: @Sergey As I said, the abbreviation is different depending on your current locale. There is no official standard.

Comment: @Sergey - Time zone abbreviations are certainly *not* standardized.  PST is also "Pitcairn Standard Time" - which is UTC-8 without daylight savings.  But more importantly consider "CST" which can be Central US, China, or Cuba.  Also "IST" which can be India, Israel, or Ireland.  Others like Hawaii could be either "HST" or "HAST"... and many time zones have no "real" abbreviation at all.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers mentioning `timeZoneWithName` are correct but there's one more detail I don't think has been mentioned. The reason that `timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT` doesn't work is that GMT does not have daylight savings time (or summer time, as it's more sensibly called in some other countries). GMT doesn't jump forward or back; it always moves ahead by one second per second. Since you ask for a fixed number of seconds from GMT, the result also does not have GMT. If it gave you a time zone that observed daylight saving time, the number of seconds from GMT would have to change twice a year. But since you asked for a fixed number of seconds, you get a result that doesn't do that, and never reports daylight saving time in effect.